# How to substitute repeating controls using partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form in an ASP.NET Core MVC project with many similar control blocks.

I would like replace these blocks with partial views, view components, or something...

These partial views should display label, value and unit for properties of main model.

The unit e.g. `[kg]` is provided as a string for now, but also could be used custom properties' attributes.

I would like use tag helpers in these elementary views.

Main view:

```
@model WebCalc.Models.Calc

<div>
    <label asp-for="Weight" class="control-label"></label>
    <label class="control-label unit">[kg]</label>
    <input asp-for="Weight" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div>
    <label asp-for="Height" class="control-label"></label>
    <label class="control-label unit">[cm]</label>
    <input asp-for="Height" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you stuck on?